# How to knit Rmarkdown files without the need to run the codes

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am not sure how to express my question in a well-understood manner. Anyway, my problem is that when I knit the Rmarkdown file, R rerun everything in the file (import data, run models, etc.), which takes a lot of time. Is there a way I can have the output of the models, data frames, graphs, or tables and save that as objects then use these objects as they are without running the process that generated them again during knitting?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't run the code to generate them, how do you expect Rmarkdown to include them in the report?  Your only option is to save the various objects to file when you create them and have a flag in your code that indcates whether they are to be generated anew or imported from file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your best option is to use the `cache` capabilities in RMarkdown: `{r cache=TRUE}`.

Se more here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache.html

Answer (score 1):

I find it's effective to do the data preparation and model fitting in a separate .Rmd or .R file and save the resulting data frames and model objects with `save`.

The notebook I create with figures and tables simply loads the objects in the first chunk with `load`.  That way I can easily iterate on the visualizations and tables without having to re-run the models every time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at R Notebooks:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/notebook.html

Notebooks are just like markdown, but with exactly the feature you are looking for.